# how to make custom paging in web2py depend on bootstrap?

Tags: python, pagination, web2py

I want to make custom paging using web2py and bootstrap

How to implement model and controller and view in a custom method without using default method like below

The default way is:

```
 def index():
    fields=[db.table_name.field1,db.table_name.field2]
    grid=SQLFORM.grid(db.table_name.id>0, deletable=False, details=False, create=False, editable=False, paginate=10, csv=False, searchable=False,user_signature=False,showbuttontext=False,fields=fields)
    return dict(grid=grid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code and its working properly

Note: this paging code need bootstrap to be exist

Add in the models new file named `paging.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import math

def base_url():
    return 'http://'+request.env.http_host+'/project_name+'/'

def pagination(total ,  page ,  Take ,  offset , controller_name , view_name , Params):
    try:
        cont_view = controller_name+'/'+view_name
        rowPerPage = Take
        if total < Take:
            rowPerPage = total
            totalPage = 0
        totalPage = 0;
        if total != 0 :
            #totalPage = int(total / rowPerPage)
            totalPage = int(math.ceil(total/float(rowPerPage)))
        current = page
        record = offset
        pageStart = current - offset
        pageEnd = current + offset
        numPage = "";
        if totalPage < 1:
            return ""
        numPage += "<ul class='pagination'>"
        if current > 1:
            numPage += "<li class='previous'><a href='"+base_url()+cont_view+"/?page="+str(page-1)+Params+"' aria-label='Previous'><span>&laquo;</span></a></li>"
        else :
            numPage += "<li class='disabled'><a href='#' aria-label='Previous'><span aria-hidden='true'>&laquo;</span></a></li>";
        if current > (offset + 1):
            numPage += "<li><a href='"+base_url()+cont_view+"/?page=1"+Params+"' name='page1'>1</a></li><li class='disabled spacing-dot'><a href='#'> ...</a> </li>"
        i = 0
        while i < totalPage:
           i = i+1
           if (pageStart <= i and pageEnd >= i) :
                if (i == current):
                    numPage += "<li class='active'><a href='#'>"+str(i)+" <span class='sr-only'>(current)</span></a></li>"
                else:
                   numPage += "<li><a href='" +base_url()+cont_view+"/?page="+str(i)+Params+ "'>" + str(i) + "</a></li>"

        if (totalPage > pageEnd) :
            record = offset
            numPage += "<li class='disabled spacing-dot'><a href='#'> ...</a></li><li><a class='ui-bar-d' href='" +base_url() +cont_view+"/?page="+str(totalPage)+Params+ "'>" + str(totalPage) + "</a></li>"
        if (current < totalPage) :
            numPage += "<li class='next'><a class='ui-bar-d' href='" + base_url() +cont_view+"/?page="+str(page+1)+Params+ "'>&raquo;</a></li>"
        else :
            numPage += "<li class='disabled'><a href='#' aria-label='Previous'><span aria-hidden='true'>&raquo;</span></a></li>";
            numPage += "</ul>"
        return (numPage);
    except ValueError:
        return("")
```

You can used in your controller like the below:

```
def index():
    take = 10

    if not request.vars.page:
        page = 1
    else:
       page = int(request.vars.page)
    skip = 0;
    if (page == 1):skip = 0
    else:skip = ((page - 1) * take)

    total  = db(db.table_name.id>0).count()
    paging = pagination(total ,  page ,  take ,  1 ,'default' , 'index' , '')
    data = db(db.table_name.id>0).select(db.table_name.field1, db.table_name.field2 , limitby=(skip,take*page))
    return dict(data = data , paging=paging , b_url = base_url())
```

After that you can call it in the view like this:

```
         <table class="table table-striped">
     <tbody><tr class="conHeader">
        <th colspan="4"><strong><span>field 1 title</span></strong></th>
        <th colspan="3"><strong><span>field 2 title</span></strong></th>
    </tr>
{{for item in data:}}
     <tr class="">
        <td colspan="4"><strong><span>{{=item.field1}}</span></strong></td>
           <tr class="">
        <td colspan="4"><strong><span>{{=item.field2}}</span></strong></td>  
    </tr>       
{{pass}}
</tbody>
        </table>

   {{=XML(paging)}}
```